# How do I move a block of code with the mouse in Xcode, drag and drop style

Tags: xcode, swiftui, wwdc

How do I drag blocks of code, specifically SwiftUI views, around with my mouse in Xcode?

In this video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10033/ about making widgets in swift, the author drags a block of code with his mouse. Between 4:50 and 4:57 he moves a VStack into a ZStack by nicely dragging it instead of cut and paste.

I have been searching, clicking, dragging, ctrl-shift-right-clicking, trying all sorts of things to do this. All my Google searches just come up with command+option+] or I hit how to *implement* drag and drop code, not how to drag and drop *code*, if you know what I mean.

I am using XCode 13.0

Comment: It works fine for me! Maybe you are missing some thing! Select the block of code then start clicking on the parent of block then drag where you want then drop!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret here is you have to hold down the mouse before starting to move the block of code, and no command / alt / option trickery is needed. I was basically running down the hill when I just needed to walk down the hill.

I will resist the urge to delete this, it seems like a dumb question now, but there must be one other person at least out there this might help.

Comment: When I triple click and drag through a case statement to select, then what? Hold down the mouse? It was held down during selection. If I let go then hold it down it deselects. Why can't this just work as expected? I want to be able to select something then drag a copy away. Usually option or something is held down to indicate copying.